# Find index of an image inside a div using a string variable

Tags: jquery

```
<img class="imgT" src='imgT/01.jpg' alt="img">
<div id="store">
  <img src="imgT/05.jpg" alt="img">
  <img src="imgT/01.jpg" alt="img">
  <img src="imgT/04.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

js

```
var x = $(".imgT").attr("src");  // imgT/01.jpg
```

I need to find index of that image inside `#store` div.

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
var index = $("#store").children().find(x).index();
alert (index);  // should be 1
```

I got the error:
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: imgT/01.jpg`

Comment: you say it should be 1, but what value do you get?

Comment: @xaxxon, I got an error. Please check my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var x = $(".imgT").attr("src");
var index = $("#store").find('img[src="'+x+'"]').index();
alert (index)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rsvh8L38/)

Answer (score 1):

Find looks in descendants, but you've already called "children" on your div.  Your children don't have any descendants.

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Lose the .children call, it's not necessary.

Also, I don't believe that's a valid use of find() -- read the docs.  I Don't see anything that takes a random value string and searches for that value in element attributes.

Here's what you want:

`alert($("#store").find("img[src='imgT/01.jpg']").index());`

This takes the #store div, calls `find` to search it's descendants for an `img` tag with the src you want.  You can use text substitution to put in your 'x' variable instead of the hard coded 01.jpg string.